# When using UTF-8, is it better to reference character for international use using decimal or hex... and why?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, html-entities

When using UTF-8, which character reference is better, or more widely supported worldwide on various browsers... using decimal references or hex references?

**UPDATE**

For instance, for replacing quotation marks...

```
&#34;  or  &#x22;
```

which one is better to use, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTML entities use only the ASCII subset, so the fact that you encode your document in UTF-8, as opposed to any other byte oriented encoding which extends ASCII, is unrelated.

Anyway:

- When using UTF-8, you can just copy and paste the relevant characters into the document, *without* references at all. E.g. StackOverflow does not convert this ⫅ to an entity (see the source of this page).
- If you prefer using entities, then I would use the hex references purely since this is the way Unicode codepoints are usually written in the charts. References are so widely supported that I do not think that you will head a compatibility problem with neither hex nor decimal references.

Comment: @ybungalobill.For me it is not such an issue of using the HTML entities within a web page, but rather an easier way to safely send data of an HTML type back and forth from the server to avoid special characters becoming a security problem.

Comment: @Epiphany: How special characters may be a security problem? In any case the security burden lies on the part that interprets the data, not the way you encode and transmit the document. I always preferred using UTF-8 directly, without entities, since it is more compact and straightforward. Besides, even IE renders it correctly.

Comment: Any unexpected character data sent to a server can pose a security risk, and those characters can be different depending on the language the back-end is using to process the data. Trying to parse out those security risks is much easier when taking a white-list approach, as there are numerous pages here that will tell you why you can not make a black-list approach either practical nor safe.

Comment: I don't think you will find any particularly unsafe characters in the pure Unicode range; security problems usually occur when ASCII characters with a metacharacter usage in a processing layer is passed around without proper quoting or escaping.

Comment: @Epiphany: I think your understanding of what constitutes a security risk is incorrect. You *should* accept all of Unicode, and there is nothing unsafe in it. (OK, in the worst case it may be unpleasant if someone inserts strange characters into his nick, but on the other hand practically any character can be legitimate in some cases.) For example I hate FB for disallowing the U+1f44e character...

Comment: ... Famous last words; next thing you know there will be an exploit which usesto gain unrestricted kernel privileges.

Comment: @ybungalobill. Sorry for the late response, chemo had me down for a bit, and I've excepted your answer for being first, but not complete answer I was looking for, and upvote Jukka for the missing piece, and another upvote tripleee for thinking along my same thought lines. Like I always tell my wife... it's just a computer and anything is possible as long as you figure out the right sequence of binary data to use. Never say never!

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference between decimal references and hexadecimal references. Old browsers [did not support](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/charset/i18n-browser-tests.html) the latter, but then we are talking about *really* old browsers like Netscape 4 and IE 4.

Hexadecimal references are usually more handy, because in character code standards and other reference works, characters are referred to by their code numbers in hexadecimal. Using them, you avoid the conversion from hexadecimal to decimal (and thereby may avoid some mistakes).

There is no reason to use either `&#34;` or `&#x22;` in text. (In attribute values, they, or `&quot;`, are needed in rare cases.)

This does not depend on the document encoding (UTF-8 or something else), except in the sense that when using UTF-8, you do not need the references (except for the markup-significant characters `<` and `&`). UTF-8 lets you enter any character as such, though you might still use references if you find that more comfortable than finding an editor that lets you enter the characters themselves.

Comment: Upvote for completion of my question with the remaining parts of the answer I was seeking.